# Making smaller lower-higher console game

Tags: console

So im a pretty new programmer so forgive me if i make any mistakes.
I need to make a higher or lower game for my class but im a little bit stuck now.
The purpose of this whole game is to guess the number which is random generated by the computer. But here's the tricky part, the user only needs to get 8 chances to guess the number right. If not the game must end and print something like: you lost, the number was.....

I came this far;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int timesGuessed = 0;
        int randomNummer = (int)(Math.random()*100);
        int number;
        boolean won = true;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        do{
            System.out.print("Guess the number: ");
            number = input.nextInt();

            timesGuessed++;

            if(timesGuessed == 8){
                won = false;

            }

            if(number > randomNummer){
                System.out.println("Lower!");
            }
            else if(number < randomNummer){
                System.out.println("Higher!");
            } 
        }
        while(number != randomNummer);

        if(won == true){
                System.out.println("The number is guessed right in " + timesGuessed + " attemts.");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You lost. The number was " + randomNummer + ".");
        }
}
```

Now the game lets you finish even though you already had 8 chances. Thats what i want to change. It needs to stop when you failed the eight time.

Thank you for the help, it would be very appreciated.

Comment: put a `break` statement after `won = false;`

Comment: Please do not SHOUT YOUR QUESTIONS here. It makes them more difficult to read, and is not going to get you help any faster. It's also quite annoying (and rather rude). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check your `won` variable in the condition of your loop. You may also want to add an `else` so it doesn't print "Higher" or "Lower" after the final try.